# Get the filename of the file from FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

I want to get the filename of the file that do not exist when a file exception occur in my java application so that i can give a short message to the user.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       /* what code to put here to get the filename of the file */
        }
```

Comment: you can get it from try block?

Comment: Have you tried `e.printStackTrace()`? What extra information do you want?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey i know about `e.printStackTrace()` but i want to get only the filename from the stacktrace so as not to confuse the average user

Comment: @user2650277 so the file name is in the message, so I suggest you get the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should display the non-existing file path:

```
try {
    //access file
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Output, for creating a `Scanner` with `new Scanner(new File("C:/filetest"))`:

> C:\filetest (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot grap properly the filename unless you parse the stacktrace in your `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the filename outside of the try block, i.e.:

```
String filename = ...
try {
   // process file
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    String message = String.format("The file % could not be found.", filename);
    // Show message to user
}
```

Or you can check whether the file exists before trying to access it:

```
 File file = new File(filename);
 if (!file.exists()) {
      // Show error to user.
 }
```